# Finding an Operator from its Commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to derive a general form for the linear operator $L_z$(rotational momentum in Quantum mechanics) which is a combination of the four linear operators

$$X, Y, P_X, P_Y$$

solely based on knowing its commutators. We know that all the four operators commute except for $X$ and $P_X$, and $Y$ and $P_Y$. More specifically:

$$ [X, P_X] = I = \text{the identity function} $$

$$ [Y, P_Y] = I = \text{the identity function} $$

Where $[., .]$ is the commutator of two operators such that $[A, B] = AB - BA$. (I know in quantum mechanics the right hand side is not $1$ and is $i\hbar$, but that's irrelevant to the general idea of the problem)

We know that:

$$ L_z = \sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta=0}^{\infty} c_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,\delta} X^\alpha Y^\beta P_x^\gamma P_y^\delta + d_{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta} P_x^{\alpha} P_Y^\beta X^\gamma Y^\delta $$

We also know the commutators of $L_z$ with the four operators:

$$ [L_z, X] = -Y $$

$$ [L_z, Y] = X $$

$$ [L_z, P_X] = -P_Y $$

$$ [L_z, P_Y] = P_X $$

From quantum mechanics we know (one possible solution) is $L_Z = X P_Y - Y P_X$. But how can one find the general form of $L_z$?

I derived the equation below which might come in handy:(it also works for $y$)

$$ [X^{a}, P_X^{b}] = \sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\sum_{n=0}^{b-1} \begin{pmatrix}b-1 \\ n\end{pmatrix} P_X^{b-1-n} X^{m} P_X^n $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(ring_theory)) of the [Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) (the algebra generated by $X, Y, P_X, P_Y$) consists of scalar multiples of the identity, so the answer is that you can recover $L$ up to a scalar multiple of the identity; in other words, the general solution is $X P_Y - Y P_X + c I$ for some scalar $c$. The argument is very similar to the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540758/an-example-of-a-non-commutative-ring-with-multiplicative-identity-1-in-which-the/2540826#2540826) which shows that the Weyl algebra is simple by repeatedly applying commutators.

Comment: Thanks! I was not familiar with Weyl algebras, so whatever solution we find will only be unique up to the elements that are in the centre of the ring, where in our case happens to be only multiples of identity.

Comment: Yes. You need to prove a small lemma here: a priori the center consists of elements $z$ such that every commutator $[z, w]$ vanishes and you need to prove it suffices to check this condition on a set of generators inserted into $w$.